# TF30036: You are unauthorized to access https://

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I've found quite a few posts of similar issues, but I still am having trouble getting this resolved.

I have a TFS repository I know I have access to with my Microsoft account.  I'm currently using it on my laptop as I'm typing this, and if I go there via chrome, I am having no issues.

I finally got my desktop up and running again, and after a fresh windows/VS 2013 install, I am getting unauthorized when trying to connect to team projects.  I'm using the same credentials that are being using through Visual Studio on my laptop, and in chrome.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Is it possible you have both a Work account (Azure Active Directory) and a Microsoft Account with the same address?

Comment: I don't recall, when they first set up the repository, all I did was sign in with my Microsoft account.  I don't recall having a separate account set up or anything.

Comment: Have you cleared old entries from the Credential Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below ways to narrow down the issue.

- Try to disable the Antivirus software on your desktop
- Try to disable your firewall on your desktop and try again
- If you are using VPN on your desktop, please disable it.
- [Clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) in your desktop.
- Clear the account info from the Credential Manager (Control Panel) both in
  your laptop and desktop, then try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Team -> Manage Connexions... -> re-select your project

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio > Reboot all servers in the Topology.